# Chaining observables and passing result values

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to translate the following code into a reactive flow (using `System.Reactive` in C#).

`Method1`, `Method2` and `Method3` are long running tasks. The result of `Method2` is necessary in order to call `Method3`, but `Method1` and `Method2` can run in parallel. If `result1 == null` the whole operation can be terminated early with `null`.

Usually, `Method2` returns faster than `Method1`, so `Method3` could be started before `Method1` finishes.

```cs
var result1 = Method1();
if (result1 == null) return null;

var result2 = Method2();

string result3 = null;
if (result2 != null)
{
    result3 = Method3(result2);
}

var combinedResult = CreateResult(result1);
if (result2 != null)
{
    combinedResult.Attr2 = result2;
}
if (result3 != null)
{
    combinedResult.Attr3 = result3;
}
```

I am lost between nested functions and generics. The following code does not compile, because it has issues with generics and return types (especially the nested `Select` does not return a value but an `Observable`).

```cs
var observable1 = Observable.Start(() => Method1());
var observable2 = Observable.Start(() => Method2());
Observable.Zip(observable1, observable2, (result1, result2) =>
{
    if (result2 != null)
    {
        var observable3 = Observable.Start(() => Method3(result2));
        return observable3.Select(result3 => 
        {
            return SuperCombiner(result1, result2, result3);
        };
    }
    return SuperCombiner(result1, null, null);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need to get this to work:

```
var inner =
    from m2 in Observable.Start(() => Method2())
    from m3 in Observable.Start(() => Method3(m2))
    select new { m2, m3 };

var query =
    Observable
        .Start(() => Method1())
        .Publish(m1s =>
            m1s
                .Zip(
                    inner.TakeUntil(m1s.Where(m1 => m1 == null)),
                    (m1, m23) => new { m1, m23.m2, m23.m3 }))
        .Where(x => x.m1 != null);
```

I have tested this using the following code:

```
public string Method1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method1 Start");
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));
    Console.WriteLine("Method1 End");
    return null; //"1";
}


public string Method2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method2 Start");
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0));
    Console.WriteLine("Method2 End");
    return "2";
}

public string Method3(string x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method3 Start");
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));
    Console.WriteLine("Method3 End");
    return $"3-{x}";
}
```

The query only produces a value when `Method1` returns a non-null value - otherwise it completes without producing a value.

`Method3` is executed immediately after `Method2` is complete **unless `Method1` has already returned `null` in which case `Method3` is not executed**.

This is computationally the most efficient implementation of what you asked for.

Comment: I'm agree that your code is a bit more efficient then mine. But your statement about Method3 is not true. Method3 will be executed in any case. Even more, it will be executed till the end even though the `query` notified about its completion because no one stops it.

Comment: If we are talking about an efficiency then in this particular case 'Tasks + CancellationTokens' instead of Observable will be the most efficient way.

Comment: @VitaliiIlchenko - Are you saying that `Method3` will be executed regardless in my code?

Comment: @VitaliiIlchenko - a `CancellationToken` would only be more efficient if the methods support co-operative cancellation.

Comment: yes, it will. Just put another delays for Thread.Sleep and you will see. For example: Method1 sleep - 3 secs, Method2 sleep - 2 secs and Method3 sleep - 4 secs. With such delays Method3 will always be called. And since it's called it will be executed till the end.

Comment: @VitaliiIlchenko - But if `Method1` finishes with a `null` before `Method2` completes then `Method3` is not run.

Comment: according to the question's description: "Usually, Method2 returns faster than Method1".

Comment: @VitaliiIlchenko - Yes, hence why this is more efficient to immediately run `Method3` so that it's not waiting for `Method1` to complete. My code ends as soon as `Method1` returns a `null` even if `Method2` or `Method3` is still executing.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some improvements to your draft and now it works as you described:

```
var stream1 = Observable.Start(Func1);
var stream2 = Observable.Start(Func2);

Observable.Zip(stream1, stream2, (res1, res2) =>
{
    if (res1 == null)
        return Observable.Start(() => new string[] { null });

    if (res2 == null)
        return Observable.Start(() => new string[] { res1, null });

    return Observable.Start(() => Func3(res2)).Select(res3 => new[] { res1, res2, res3 });
})
.Merge()
.Subscribe(result =>
{
    // 'result' is an array

    // result[0] - result of Func1
    // result[1] - result of Func2
    // result[2] - result of Func3

    // result.Length == 1  - means that Func1 returned 'null'
    // result.Length == 2  - means that Func2 returned 'null'
});
```

But it's not a real 'Reactive' way because it contains imperative statements (like `if` operators for example).

Comment: Thank you, your solution is working. I just had to replace `Subscribe` with `FirstAsync`, so that I can `await` and get back into synchronous world.

Comment: There is an inefficiency here. `Method3` waits until **both** `Method1` and `Method2` are completed. The OP asks for "`Method3` could be started before `Method1` finishes" but that doesn't happen in this code.

Comment: I agree: The code above is "`Method1 and Method2` in parallel, only  then `Method3` will be called". In the meantime I also implemented a solution with regular 'Tasks', which does exactly what I want. But I still would like to find the "ideal" reactive solution - I known that this is not real 'reactive' because of the given constraints.